# Embedded ActiveX analog using Django

Tags: django, activex

This might be a naive question, but when using a python framework, what approaches are available to provide the kind of functionality that can be exposed using an ActiveX control as an embedded object. The specific example I have in mind is a third party ocx we are using in some ASP.NET pages to provide TWAIN interaction on the client side. I'd like to avoid browser and platform specific approaches, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confused. If you're talking client-side, it makes no difference whether you are using Python or ASP.NET on the server - you can still embed the object in the HTML and the client will run it, assuming they are using Internet Explorer. However, this already is a browser- and platform-specific approach.

The best alternatives are probably Flash and Silverlight - although the latter is from Microsoft, it is pretty well cross-platform now since all the main browsers and OSs have implementations of it. Flash is still more widespread for now, though.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The goal is to replace the ActiveX with an alternative technology that supports client side browser plugability and execution, not to get it to work with django. i.e., if were to find a good set of python modules that handled TWAIN, how would I expose that to the client's browser.